# Runtime Permissions: QR Reader

Tags: android, permissions, camera, zxing, runtime-permissions

I am working on a QR Reader Application, I need some help in the Runtime Permission for Android M and later.

Problem: I am able to Request for Permission and even get a permission for Camera. But, the package manager is causing a problem. I have copied the Runtime permission from some website and shortened it only for camera permissions.

Case: When I install the App for the first time and click the Button which invokes the camera (it is asking for Camera Permission), I grant the permission. Next, it opens the Package manager and I select my device camera. Now it opens the Device Camera. Not the Zxing mscanner (QR framework) camera.

Below is my code, sure about I  will get some help here.

My requirement is: When I allow the camera on the first launch of the app and hit the Scan button, it should open as normal QR Scanner. It was working fine without Runtime permissions, but now – I want to learn about RTP more for future use.

For testing, I am using a Marshmallow and Nougat.

For both, I am manually giving permission and I have got to know that I need to solve this using Runtime Permission for latest devices/OS. I am close to it, but I need some logical help.

```
//QR Scanner App using Zebra Crossing Framework Sample HAve to User Run time
//Permissions for only Camera for API Level 23 and above

    import com.google.zxing.Result;
    import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;
    //Above imports
    import static android.R.attr.permission;
    import static android.media.MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
        private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

        static final Integer CAMERA = 0x5;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    }


    //Nougat and Marshmallow
    //ask for permission    
    private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    //asking for permission prompt

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permission)) {
    //request for permissions and getting request code -- 5 for camera
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);

                } else {
    //requesting permission
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "" + permission + " is already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    //Response for RunTime Permissions
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                switch (requestCode) {
                    //Camera
                    case 5:
                        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 12);
                        }
                       // askForPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,CAMERA);
                        break;

                }

                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
else
{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    //Runtime Permissions Done above

    //QR Scanner Invokation below
        public void QrScanner(View view){
            askForPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,CAMERA);

            mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
            setContentView(mScannerView);

            mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); for scan results.
            mScannerView.startCamera();         // Start camera

        }

    //code ends here
```

Comment: Hi, I have found a solution for this.  I just called mScannerView.startCamera() in the Response for RunTimePermissions. Any better implementation for this functionality.

Comment: Check out my library which may come handy while using runtime permissions. https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions